# Best way to Login a User of a Custom Software

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I have a C# WPF desktop application and I need to keep track of the current user of the program (not the Windows User, just the user registered in the program, by a registration form and saved in the programs own Data Base).

I am looking for the best way to handle this, and looking on the web just shows me ASP.NET examples or how to get the Window's current logged user. Right now I can think of these options:

1. Make a global variable that can be accessed inside the whole app and hold the user there.
2. Make a DB table to hold the current logged user after the login is validated, so checking that table everywhere in the program will give me logged user.
3. Use some kind of Class already made for this, but I have no knowledge about and you guys will tell me about it.

I like more option #1, but I would like to know if there is any "common" and "recommended" way of doing it before jumping into coding it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a `User` class that defines a user with all the info you need. Then create an instance when the user logs in, and pass that instance around as a parameter to functions etc that need it.

If you can find a .Net class that already does this, that'd be great, too! I've used Windows/Active Directory authentication in some apps, and that dovetails nicely with .Net. https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20active%20directory%20authentication

Here are a few objections I have to the other options:

- Global variables - tend to clutter code. They also tend to violate the Single-Responsibility principle
- DB table - adds complexity as you have to clean up from an unclean application exit. Also adds a little more storage requirement

Single-Responsibility principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Well I already have a user class, I just wanted to avoid passing a user all over the place for simplicity sake. And I agree with your reasons, those were my issues with those options too